# Intersection of pandas dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dataframes as:

```
[df1, df2, df3, ..., df100, oddDF]
```

Each dataframe `dfi` has `DateTime` as column1 and `Temperature` as column2. Except the dataframe `oddDF` which has `DateTime` as column1 and has temperature columns in column2 and column3.

I am looking to create a list of dataframe or one dataframe which has the common temperatures from each of `df1, .. df100 and oddDF`

I am trying the following:

```
dfs = [df0, df1, df2, .., df100, oddDF]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='DateTime'), dfs)
```

But it produces `df_final` as empty

If however I do just:

```
dfs = [df0, df1, df2, .., df100]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='DateTime'), dfs)
```

`df_final` produces the right answer.

How do I incorporate `oddDF` in the code also. I have checked to make sure that `oddDF's` `DateTime` column has the common dates with

```
df1, df2, .., df100
```

Comment: looks ok to me ... can you try doing it in two steps, ie. merge the 100 df's then do a separate merge of the final one? this might help you find the problem

Comment: It gives NAN is I split the process. I don't have a clue.

Comment: so the problem is really about merging two dataframes, not merging a list of dataframes. can you find a minimal subset of these two dataframes that reproduces the problem and include it in the question?